# Add values of column2 to the right of a row by matching column1 values

Tags: sas

I have a dataset where there are multiple subsequent entries with duplicate values of column1, and different values of column2.

Something like this :

| column1 | column2 |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 3 |

My desired output is the following :

| column1 | column2_1 | column2_2 | column2_3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 3 |

My current solution uses the RETAIN and BY group to concatenate the different values of column2, and then using scan() to separate them into their respective columns, that I lifted from [HERE](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-to-merge-multiple-rows-into-a-single-row-with-same-date-but/td-p/784782) and [HERE](https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/How-to-split-one-column-into-two-based-on-a-delimiter/td-p/611511).

I was wondering, is there a more elegant (or maybe even better, inbuilt?) method of combining rows in this manner?

Thank you.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you are asking. The first link you provided shows two simple ways. One using a data step with an ARRAY and the other using the "built-in" procedure, PROC TRANSPOSE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `proc transpose`, definitely.

```
data have;
  input column1 column2;
  cards;
1   1
1   2
1   3
2   1
2   2
2   3
;
run;

proc transpose data=have out=want prefix=column2_;
  by column1;
  var column2;
run;
```

This procedure is designed to transpose data.
However, if you insist on doing this in data step. Array method is sort
of elegant, I think.

```
data want;
  i=0;
  do until(last.column1);
    set have;
    i+1;
    array column2_[3];
    by column1;
    column2_[i]=column2;
  end;
run;
```

You may need to replace the number `3` by a macro variable to make this skill portable.

Comment: No need to increment I yourself. Just use `do i=1 by 1 until(last.column1);`

Comment: @Tom Tom, that is awsome.